# Why is my deep learning model predicting very similar but wrong values

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

So I've done some really basic supervised learning in the past and decided to try predictive maintenance and because I am new to this subject I decided to watch some tutorials in the world wide web. After a couple of hours into it i came across this specific tutorial (link down below) in which it is used a dataset from NASA (link down below) which has several values taken from several different engines. My main goal with predictive maintenance was to predict when certain object was about fail, so we could pinpoint it and avoid it by making a eventual repair.

The problem is that in this tutorial he doesn't make a model nor feeds the data to it so I decided that I should give it a try, but the results are bad despite the accuracy being almost 90%. The reason they are bad is because, like the tutorial suggests, I made a column with a variable called RUL(Remaining Useful Life) which is either 1 or 0 depending on the number of "RULs" (less than 20 it is 1 else it's 0). The RUL is calculed based of the number of cycles, so each engine starts at cycle 1 and its RUL is the max cycle it achieved minus the number of cycles, so in the next cycle(2) the RUL will be the max_cycle-2.
If this doenst make sense to you I apologize in advance. Below you can find all the code that is present in the tutorial as well as my model and attempt.

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten


# http://ti.arc.nasa.gov/c/6/
path = r"C:\Users\Ginger Bread\Desktop\archive\CMAPSSData\train_FD001.txt"
raw_data = pd.read_csv(path, sep=' ', header=None)
print(raw_data.head())

# Changing the label name
raw_data = raw_data[[f for f in range(0,26)]]
raw_data.columns = ['ID', 'Cycle', 'OpSet1', 'OpSet2', 'OpSet3', 'SensorMeasure1', 'SensorMeasure2', 'SensorMeasure3', 'SensorMeasure4', 'SensorMeasure5', 'SensorMeasure6', 'SensorMeasure7', 'SensorMeasure8', 'SensorMeasure9', 'SensorMeasure10', 'SensorMeasure11', 'SensorMeasure12', 'SensorMeasure13', 'SensorMeasure14', 'SensorMeasure15', 'SensorMeasure16', 'SensorMeasure17', 'SensorMeasure18', 'SensorMeasure19', 'SensorMeasure20', 'SensorMeasure21']
print(raw_data)

# Checking what is the max number of Cycles for each id engine
max_cycles_df = raw_data.groupby(['ID'], sort=False)['Cycle'].max().reset_index().rename(columns={'Cycle':'MaxCycleID'})
print(max_cycles_df.head())

# merge back to original dataset
FD001_df = pd.merge(raw_data, max_cycles_df, how='inner', on='ID')
FD001_df['RUL'] = FD001_df['MaxCycleID'] - FD001_df['Cycle']
print(FD001_df)
print(FD001_df[['Cycle', 'RUL']])


print('Shape:', FD001_df.shape)
print(list(FD001_df))

# create outcome variable
print(len(FD001_df[FD001_df['RUL'] == 0]))

# plot them
one_engine = []
for i, r in FD001_df.iterrows():
    rul = r['RUL']
    one_engine.append(rul)
    if rul == 0:
        plt.plot(one_engine)
        one_engine = []
plt.show()

# Write to file
FD001_df.to_csv('NASA_Full_FD001.csv', index=None)

# Create a smaller data set for classification
pred_maint_data = FD001_df[['Cycle',
                            'SensorMeasure11',
                            'SensorMeasure4',
                            'SensorMeasure9',
                            'SensorMeasure14',
                            'RUL']]
print(pred_maint_data.head())


# Create a binary outcome - we'll assume 20 days
# Percent of time RUL at 0
pt0 = len(pred_maint_data[pred_maint_data['RUL'] == 0])/len(pred_maint_data) * 100
print('Percent of time RUL at 0:', np.round(pt0,2), '%')

# create outcome variable of 1 or 0
pred_maint_data['RUL'] = [1 if out < 20 else 0 for out in pred_maint_data['RUL']]

pt0 = np.mean(pred_maint_data['RUL']) * 100
print('Percent of time RUL at 0:', np.round(pt0,2), '%')
print(pred_maint_data['RUL'].value_counts())

# save to file
pred_maint_data.to_csv('NASA_20_Cycles_Failure_FD001.csv', index=None)

# End of the tutorial Code
# Below this comment, the code was made by me

# Getting the data from a csv file and dividing it into train and test sets

data = pd.read_csv("NASA_20_Cycles_Failure_FD001.csv")

train = data.drop(['RUL', 'Cycle'], axis=1)
test = data['RUL']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train, test, test_size=0.2, random_state=2)
print("HERE")
print(X_train)
print("HERE2")
print(y_train)

# Model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4, init='uniform', input_shape=(4,), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(16, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(16, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fit the model
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=3, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True)

score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=2)
print(score)

print(history.history.keys())

plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'], label='train')
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='loss')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# Seeing the predictions
predictions = model.predict(X_test)

print("Predictions")
for i in predictions:
    print(i)
    if i >= 0.5:
        print("ALELUIA")
print("Real values")
for u in y_test:
    print(u)
```

I've tried to change the number of RUL to be 1 when the value is different than 20 and the accuracy also changes but the predictions still end up being almost identical which makes the predictions round up to either all 0 or all 1. Below I'll put the results of each prediction as well as the real value (y_test).

Note: I should probably have changed the name of the column RUL to "needs fixing" after the transformation for either 1 or 0 accordingly.

```
Predictions
[0.1050983]
[0.10404325]
[0.10555065]
[0.10555321]
[0.10344189]
[0.10533005]
[0.10478833]
[0.1051653]
[0.10526326]
[0.10516419]
[0.1038975]
[0.10515215]
[0.10531015]
[0.10511505]
[0.10518976]
[0.1050439]
[0.1051843]
[0.10559492]
[0.10387661]
[0.10374805]
[0.10509399]
[0.10515141]
[0.10521074]
[0.1052593]
[0.10540438]
[0.10533711]
[0.10501852]
[0.10463601]
[0.10503829]
[0.10521385]
[0.10441336]
[0.105217]
[0.10531073]
[0.10491394]
[0.10537319]
[0.10523231]
[0.10557146]
[0.1047653]
[0.10525884]
[0.10500285]
[0.10505348]
[0.10541109]
[0.10533073]
[0.10517488]
[0.1050622]
[0.10527248]
[0.1051841]
[0.10544233]
[0.10554202]
[0.10465073]
[0.10464738]
[0.10524271]
[0.10522015]
[0.10502062]
[0.10546359]
[0.10409129]
[0.10522158]
[0.1051973]
[0.10548837]
[0.10525122]
[0.10466116]
[0.10534483]
[0.10547991]
[0.10514109]
[0.10531491]
[0.10518854]
[0.10496807]
[0.10505583]
[0.10516969]
[0.10521539]
[0.10524863]
[0.10527457]
[0.10532214]
[0.10324776]
[0.10544115]
[0.10540842]
[0.10515314]
[0.10515888]
[0.10483669]
[0.10501605]
[0.104861]
[0.10495911]
[0.10525009]
[0.10529111]
[0.10487738]
[0.10509273]
[0.10518468]
[0.10503055]
[0.10417407]
[0.10479013]
[0.10534652]
[0.10522777]
[0.10319146]
[0.10549013]
[0.10530148]
[0.10484377]
[0.10440563]
[0.10472738]
[0.10502187]
[0.10525076]
[0.10510702]
[0.10532416]
[0.10381923]
[0.1054415]
[0.1054302]
[0.10558783]
[0.10514364]
[0.10523658]
[0.10515053]
[0.10526689]
[0.10520654]
[0.10515639]
[0.10531743]
[0.10403327]
[0.10531391]
[0.10477831]
[0.10548837]
[0.10522526]
[0.10505868]
[0.10418756]
[0.1053642]
[0.10524843]
[0.10497409]
[0.10368675]
[0.10495283]
[0.10515259]
[0.10517113]
[0.1049794]
[0.10523032]
[0.10518576]
[0.1050372]
[0.10507836]
[0.10503409]
[0.10540656]
[0.10431397]
[0.10471103]
[0.10531015]
[0.10523356]
[0.10539803]
[0.10527551]
[0.10513147]
[0.10511173]
[0.10527663]
[0.10504944]
[0.10528576]
[0.10536461]
[0.10493658]
[0.10516817]
[0.10531207]
[0.10546369]
[0.10419846]
[0.10411397]
[0.10465484]
[0.10431477]
[0.10501323]
[0.10528364]
[0.10537661]
[0.10482613]
[0.10522176]
[0.10495919]
[0.10519546]
[0.10520439]
[0.10508794]
[0.10462283]
[0.10532165]
[0.10358283]
[0.10522396]
[0.105164]
[0.10544351]
[0.10536326]
[0.10539526]
[0.10498454]
[0.10327268]
[0.10522733]
[0.10537484]
[0.10505765]
[0.10524735]
[0.10499822]
[0.10508626]
[0.10388456]
[0.1051572]
[0.10503815]
[0.10507942]
[0.10505755]
[0.10536408]
[0.105366]
[0.10546079]
[0.10522104]
[0.10485433]
[0.10520129]
[0.10539605]
[0.10529195]
[0.10493235]
[0.10515185]
[0.10532335]
[0.10540719]
[0.10522908]
[0.10535663]
[0.10558803]
[0.10517517]
[0.10549721]
[0.10537575]
[0.10507962]
[0.10530768]
[0.10452699]
[0.10524847]
[0.10516036]
[0.10510545]
[0.10540862]
[0.10508175]
[0.10522414]
[0.10484162]
[0.10526936]
[0.10518522]
[0.10485084]
[0.10538556]
[0.10537019]
[0.10549224]
[0.10515653]
[0.10519943]
[0.10512082]
[0.10544203]
[0.10487756]
[0.10497619]
[0.10518141]
[0.10533778]
[0.10509621]
[0.10531738]
[0.10505059]
[0.10514385]
[0.10523034]
[0.10531139]
[0.10385931]
[0.1056235]
[0.10516278]
[0.10499334]
[0.10527273]
[0.10524946]
[0.10525396]
[0.10490155]
[0.10441212]
[0.10487241]
[0.10538799]
[0.1049312]
[0.10491467]
[0.10517243]
[0.10535877]
[0.10543416]
[0.10509314]
[0.1049196]
[0.10501852]
Real values
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
1
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

As you can see it gives me always numbers near 0 which make the model seem to have a good accuracy since there is a lot of 0s in the y_test but it fails in the most important ones which are the 1s which tell me when the engine needs to be fixed! If you know what's happening and would like to help me I would be very much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Note2: The amount of predictions and y_test values showed was drastically reduced in orded to fit in the body text.

Helpful links:

[Youtube Video - Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GBO2GNmEzk&list=LL6k0JudHwRwQIMFDjZK7ooA&index=1&t=1261s&ab_channel=ManuelAmunategui)

[Raw Code - Tutorial](https://www.viralml.com/video-content.html?fm=yt&v=4GBO2GNmEzk)

[Dataset - NASA](http://ti.arc.nasa.gov/c/6/)

Versions:

Windows 10
Keras 2.2.0
Tensorflow 1.12.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, you're using `'mean_squared_error'` loss. MSE is good for when you're trying to predict an analog number. However, your ground truth here is a binary prediction: either 0 or 1. In this case, you should be trying to predict a category, not a real value. For that, you want [binary cross-entropy](https://keras.io/api/losses/probabilistic_losses/#binarycrossentropy-class). So, change `loss='mean_squared_error'` to `loss='binary_crossentropy'`.

Additionally, it seems that you might not be training it for long enough, <del>and with a batch size too large. If you don't specify batch size in `model.fit`, I believe that it defaults to a batch size equal to the whole dataset. This would mean that your model's parameters get updated only once per epoch.</del> At the moment, you have it set to only train for 3 epochs. The next thing I would try would be setting a batch size of maybe 32, and running it for many more epochs, e.g. maybe 10 to 100 depending on how big the dataset is. So you should have something like

```
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=30, batch_size=32, ...
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer but unfortunately it did not fix my problem. I've also tried to use Dropout between some of the layers and the values have increased overall (0.166) but they are still very similiar to each other and none actually predicts anything above 0.5 which makes final predictions all zero. If you have any other ideas let me know. Thanks!

Comment: @BlueRoss I took a closer look and added more to my answer

Comment: So, I've tried your suggestion and increased the epochs as well as set a batch_size to 32 but sadly the results were similar. I've also tried with different epochs and different batch_size (9, 3, ..) but the results were similar to the previous ones. Here is a print of the training https://prnt.sc/upjplk . Nevertheless I've come across a classifier named "RidgeClassifier" from sklearn and although it doesn't predict all the 1's it predicted 193 out of 417 which at least is something. I'll continue to try to improve it but I just wanted to let you know! Maybe I should accept your answer?

Comment: @BlueRoss not sure what else the problem could be, sorry. I would say that it might simply not be possible to predict based on the data you have, but since it's a tutorial dataset then I assume it must be possible. If my answer didn't solve the issue for you, I'd say don't accept it. Although I appreciate the sentiment, you should usually only accept answers that solved the problem for you or were integral in leading you to the solution.

Comment: If batch_size is not specified in fit(), it defaults to 32

Comment: @JR Thanks for pointing that out! It looks like I was confused about how it was handled, since some dataset types have their own implicit batch sizes, and dataframes weren't explicitly mentioned in the documentation. I believe that dataframes are now explicitly treated like numpy arrays, which default to 32 as you say.

Answer (score 1):

For Binary Clasification, I would agree to use "binary_crossentropy".  Try early stopping too.

```
from tensorflow.keras import callbacks

early_stopping = callbacks.EarlyStopping(
            monitor = 'val_loss',
            mode = 'auto',
            patience = 20,
            min_delta = 0.001,
            restore_best_weights = True,
            verbose = 1

# learning_rate schedule
lr_schedule = callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(
            monitor = 'val_loss',
            mode = 'auto',
            patience = 0,
            factor = 0.2,
            min_lr = 3e-4,
            verbose = 1
        )

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
          validation_data = (X_valid, y_valid),
          batch_size = 2048,
          epochs = 200,
          callbacks=[early_stopping,
                     self.lr_schedule]
          )
```

And for predicting, output either 0 or 1:

```
predictions = (model.predict(X_test) >= 0.5).astype("int32")

asm = (accuracy_score(y_test, predictions.round()) * 100)
print('Accuracy for model: %.2f %%' % asm)
```

I also prefer the functional API method over Sequential(), but that's another topic